# Is this below usage of instanceof is bad programing

Tags: java

I am trying a piece of code in the way below.

```
 public void doSomething(){

           makeMethodCall(car);

           statement1......
           statement2......

         makeMethodCall(bike);

            statement3......

         makeMethodCall(bicycle);

    }


   private void makeMethodCall(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Car){
                 obj.drive();
        }
          if(obj instanceof Bike){
                 obj.drive();
        }
            if(obj instanceof Bicycle){
                 obj.drive();
        }
        // There are many if loops
      }
```

I am thinking that I am doing some kind of wrong activity. Is there anyway I can handle this programming using lamba expression. I am new to java8 and I find tricky the use of lambda expressions.

Comment: Do you have an abstract class vehicle ?

Comment: Yes that's __really__ bad. Either use an abstract class or an interface like `Drivable` and use that as the method parameter type and get rid of all the `if` blocks (not "if loops").

Comment: No. Actually I like to say that the three classes have no dependency among them.

Comment: Use an interface instead or visitor pattern if this is an overly simplified  example.

Comment: This is a substantially different question now and is confusing with the given answers. Should be reverted to the original question and a new question raised.

Comment: Yeah I would do that

Comment: What are these methods for?  You probably think you have left out "unimportant" details, but in reality you have left out all the information we require to explain how horribly bad this is and how to do it better.

Comment: Before lambdas you need to understand the problem. The before and after do not require lambdas

Comment: I rolled back the question because it invalidates existing answers.  I also gave you an upvote to encourage you to ask a new question.

Comment: There is also a fundamental aspect that answers so far have not addressed. What would happen if you ever add a new type of vehicle? Your `instanceof` code above will automatically miss one entry. It is easy to forget to add it since the code will compile just fine, it would just break at runtime.

Comment: Your question is about [Preferring polymorphism over instanceof and downcasting](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html). You may also consider valid cases of usage of `instanceof`, like [instanceof versus getClass in equals Methods](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html). This other article [Polymorphism and Interfaces](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html) has section named "When to use instanceof" that I think is worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all methods in Java are virtual. 
I think, you should use interfaces:

```
interface Driveable {
  void drive();
}

class Car implements Driveable {
@Override
void drive() {
   System.out.println("Car drive");
}
}
class Bike implements Driveable {
@Override
void drive() {
   System.out.println("Bike drive");
}
}
class Bicycle implements Driveable {
@Override
void drive() {
   System.out.println("Bicycle drive");
}
}
```

and now you don't need the `makeMethodCall` method, just write

```
void doSomething(Driveable driveable) { 
  driveable.drive();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Declaring a function that accepts `Object` as a parameter is bad practice in the vast majority of cases, certainly in the case at hand.

`Car`, `Bike` and `Bicycle` should be derived from a common abstract base class `Vehicle`, which defines an abstract method `drive()`.  Then this method would be overridden in each of the derived classes.

So, instead of `makeMethodCall( object )` you would do `vehicle.drive()`.

Comment: Or an interface

Comment: @Mike: Updated the question with different scenario

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's bad. It's not easy to guess what the method wants just out of the argument list. You can instead create an interface called "Vehicle":

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public void drive();
}
```

And make every class implement it, which forces the objects to implement the drive function too:

```
public class Bike implements Vehicle { ... }
```

Then you can just use the vehicle's drive method. If the drive method is the same between all of the objects, then you can do the same with an abstract Vehicle class.

Comment: Before anyone downvotes, the question changed while I was writing it, so I have to rewrite it.

Comment: @niks same here